# Blur effect stopped working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I used the following code to create a `blur effect` and it worked fine on `iOS 10`, but it stopped working on `iOS 11`.I am not able to view the `blur` when app moves to `background`.When the app comes to `foreground`, some times,the `blur stays always`and the application no longer works,only way to make it work is by `relaunching` the app.

Is there any work around for this for `iOS 11` ?

```
-(void)addBlurEffect{
    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
    UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    UIWindow * window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    blurEffectView.frame = window.frame;
    blurEffectView.tag = 4444;
    [window addSubview:blurEffectView];

}

-(void)removeBlurEffect{
    NSArray *allWindows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    for (UIWindow * aWindow in allWindows) {
        UIView *blurEffectView = [aWindow viewWithTag:4444];
        if (blurEffectView){
            [blurEffectView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self addBlurEffect];
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self removeBlurEffect];
}
```

Comment: What sense does it make to add the blur effect when the app is in the background? The app is not running in the background; there is nothing to see. What is this code trying to do?

Comment: if you want your app to show nothing while in background for safety concerns, then you can add a view on top hiding your app screen .

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are doing it in the WRONG delegates the entire time. You need to read the documentation or the comments in `AppDelegate` on what each method does..

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.

    [self addBlurEffect];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    [self removeBlurEffect];
}
```

So think of the two methods above as "pausing" or "unpausing" a game.. When a game goes in the background or gets interrupted, typically you pause it for the user so they don't lose progress or die or something while it's in the background state or transitioning state (IE: The task manager state).

Then when they resume and the app is on screen, you unpause it. This would require refreshing and invalidation of graphics.. Which the two methods above handle..

However, you were doing it in:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
```

This method is for saving states and cleaning up.. not modifying UI.. IE: Storing stuff in a database or syncing the user settings to disk or something or releasing memory.. User can potentially kill the app in this state or the system can kill it too.

This only gets called when the application is actually minimized (minimized/background state is NOT the same as task-switcher state/in-active state!).. iOS 11 has a different transition so now we actually see the difference I guess..

If you move your code into active state handlers, it works 100% fine..

Comment: As you said in iOS 11 has different transition style, sometimes blur effect is not adding. Any idea why these delegate methods are not get called when double press on device home button?